# Deserialize Object in String to Python Dict

Tags: python, solr, deserialization

I'm using apache solr and python, when I send data in the form a dict/obj it is stored and received as

```
{
  "array": [
    "{key: value}, {key: value}, {key: value}",
    "{key: value}, {key: value}, {key: value}",
    "{key: value}, {key: value}, {key: value}"
  ],
}
```

is it possible to convert that python string into a python dict

N.B the values I'm expecting are either string or float

**Update**: I decided to use the built-in JSON encoder to serialize each instance of a nested python dictionary and send that to the SOLR instance, finally when I'm retrieving the data I just deserialize the already encoded json string

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the built-in JSON encoder to serialize each instance of a nested python dictionary and send that to the SOLR instance, finally when I'm retrieving the data I just deserialize the already encoded json string

```
import json

{
  "array": [
    json.loads({key: value, key: value, key: value}),
  ],
}
```